# Bootstrap modal vs magnific popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, magnific-popup

I came across some commercial themes (and checking their code) and they use Magnific popup while using bootstrap as well.

Since bootstrap's main purpose is to provide a responsive framework and they already provide a modal, why use Magnific popup on top of that?

I've checked Magnific popup page briefly and it seems to me that their examples can be done via Bootstrap's modal as well. Am I missing something obvious here?

(Should I dump modal in favor of Magnific popup?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Magnific Popup is more wide to use and have so many options to customize  the functionality as compare to bootstrap. Please read the below links , we will find it helpful for you.

http://www.uibox.in/item/105

http://modernui.brunomatthys.com/MANUAL/magnific-popup.html